# Software architecture entity connections

Tags: modeling, data-modeling

For learning purpose I want to create an app.

So I thought I will do something real easy to learn a lot about object oriented programming and modelling. After some thinking I had the idea to do a simple Sport-Ranking app. I thought this is very simple and I could build it up further and further.

So first, this is why I thought it is easy: Is all you need is three Entities. `Person`, `Gender` and `Race`.

They would look roughly like:

```
+--------+     +----------+     +--------+
| Person |     | Race     |     | Gender |
+--------+     +----------+     +--------+
| name   |     | name     |     | name   |
| birth  |     | date     |     +--------+
| e_mail |     | distance |
| gender |     | address  |
+--------+     +----------+
```

Now of course I was wrong. This bluddy race part is getting tricky.

So I changed race to:

```
+---------+  +------------+  +------------+  +----------+  +----------+  +--------+
| Race    |  | R_Distance |  | R_Category |  | R_Result |  | R_Number |  | R_Time |
+---------+  +------------+  +------------+  +----------+  +----------+  +--------+
| name    |  | distance   |  | category   |  | result   |  | number   |  | time   |
| date    |  +------------+  +------------+  +----------+  +----------+  +--------+
| address |
+---------+
```

I'm verry uncertain if this is right. I mean a `Race-Time` and `Race-Number` belongs to the race and also belongs to the Person. So how can I connect them?

What else should I think about? How to handle if a race has interims and laps?

Should I also have a entity `R_Rank`?

Comment: Are those R_ things all distinct tables? Would not make that much sense. Are there several 'competitions' for one race where a single person can take part? One table referencing race and person should be enough to hold the results. Maybe another table that defines the 'competition' as such that holds category & distance (then the results table would reference competition & person and have the fields result, number, time). So you can slightly reduce this maybe (though in fact you may find that you will need further tables)

Comment: Can you explain what you mean with all those entities? Especially those R_ entities.

Comment: @thorstenmüller No, they're not tables (actually). Those R_ things are Entities (we can also call them classes). So `R_Distance` is `Race_Distance` which is a part of `Race`. I'm trying to create a symfony2 project. So in symfony I guess they would say `R_Distance` is a `array_collection`. But (it's hard to explain) The `R_Distance` is a Entity (class) which gets mapped with the database. So on the database it is a table ... does this makes any sense?

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau can you please check my comment to thorstenmüller and let me know if that makes any sense..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an intermediate object for that. If a person finished a race, you would store the result of that race in a separate object: a PersonRaceResult. It would have a reference to the Person that ran and a reference to the Race the person ran, as well as properties for the result such as a Time indicating the total time to complete the Race.

If you need things like laps, your model stays about the same (assuming every lap is the same distance). Race would then probably have a NumberOfLaps property, a PersonRaceResult whould have the references to Race and Time but also a collection of PersonRaceResultLapTimes. These would have a reference back to their PersonRaceResult, as well as a LapNumber to indicate what lap was run as well as a Time which indicates the time it took for a lap. In order to get the final result time, your PersonRaceResult would loop through all the PersonRaceResultLapTimes, add all the Time-properties and return that.